# Can you please help me with getting these Toolbar icons under a floating action button so that I can save space of webpage?

Tags: java, android, toolbar, floating-action-button

[image]

I have made an app (all in one social media) in which if someone clicks (eg. facebook) then the webpage of facebook opens but the top toolbar consumes some space which can make my app users frustrated so I want to put all those toolbar icons under a floating action button.
Similar to this or I am ready to go for any other style:-
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go both ways. Either you create the menu on your own or you can use library. For example you can easily create vertical menu and there is a simple tutorial for it there:

https://mobikul.com/expandable-floating-action-button-fab-menu/

Or you can use a library. For libraries I like to go to Android Arsenal which has tons of libraries in one place:

https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=FAB+menu

One example of library you're looking for:

https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu